# jekyll on windows ,why can't work?

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I type jekyll serve
And:

```
E:\blog>jekyll serve
Configuration file: E:/blog/_config.yml
            Source: E:/blog
       Destination: E:/blog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
Error reading file C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/default.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/default.html
Error reading file C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/page.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/page.html
Error reading file C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/post.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/post.html
                    done in 3.54 seconds.
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'E:/blog'
Configuration file: E:/blog/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

It requires minima so I installed the minima, but nothing seems to work.I visited server address but nothing.

Help please.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention your version, but Jekyll 3.2.0 is broken on Windows. Updating to 3.2.1 fixes some known issues. Update Jekyll with the following command:

```
$ gem update jekyll
```

From http://jekyllrb.com/news/2016/08/02/jekyll-3-2-1-released/

> Well, 3.2.0 has been a success, but with one fatal flaw: it doesn’t work on Windows! Sorry, Windows users. Hot on the trail of 3.2.0, this release should squash that :bug:. Sorry about that!
>
> This release also fixes an issue when using gem-based themes where the theme was rejected if it existed behind a symlink. This is a common setup for the various ruby version managers, and for Ruby installed via Homebrew.

Comment: fine 3.2.1 ,but nothing changed

Comment: Does the file it's missing actually exist? C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/default.html

Comment: No,3 files all exist

Answer (score 1):

Please copy the _includes and _layouts folders under *C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/* to your repo *E:/blog/* and try to rerun this cmd '**jekyll serve**'.

Now, preview your local Jekyll site in your web browser at http://localhost:4000.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My portable Ruby/Jekyll kit:

Download `ruby-2.3.1-i386-mingw32.7z`
Some gems require `DevKit`. Download the 7z version.

Decompress both and add to your PATH. I've added the following (I use Cmder)

```
@set iii=%cli%\Ruby\bin
@set jjj=%cli%\RubyDevKit\bin\
@set kkk=%cli%\RubyDevKit\mingw\bin\
@set PATH=%PATH%%aaa%;%bbb%;%ccc%;%ddd%;%eee%;%fff%;%ggg%;%hhh%;%iii%;%jjj%;%kkk%;%lll%;
```

**Test Jekyll with a known good website:**

```
git clone https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/ testsite
cd testsite
jekyll serve
```

If Jekyll works, the problem is with something else.